# "Element Inspector" in web browser

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, iframe, same-origin-policy

I like the Chrome Developer's feature of "Element Selection", i.e. the feature where a user can hover over a page, see elements marked-up and the values within them. I understand how this could be built for a 'thick client' tool, e.g. Chrome, which has full access to the web-page. But could this be emulated as a browser-based solution, where one website can do "Element Selection" on another website? I'm asking because I feel that it may not be possible, due to browser security controls that limit one website accessing another website (whether second site is in an IFRAME or otherwise).

Comment: `browser security controls that limit one website accessing another website` exactly